# How to get project folder on a VSIX project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsx

I'm developing an extension for VS2015 and i need to get the project folder of the opened solution. And then find the bin folder to get the output DLL.
All this because i need to instantiate a class from the output DLL using reflection.

I tried to get some information from msdn but it's difficult to me understand.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The solution itself does not have an output folder, but the solution can contain multiple projects - and each project has it´s own output directory (which depends on the selected solution configuration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this...

Find the project file of interest (maybe the startup project), or let the user select it. The project output directory is stored within it´s project file, so one should use `MSBuild` to read that information, or the better: let `MSBuild` evaluate the project assembly´s target path property. What you need would be the absolute path of the project file, or an `EnvDTE.Project` reference.

The absolute path to an output assembly can be obtained by evaluating the `TargetPath` property. You need to reference the `Microsoft.Build.dll` assembly, create a new project-collection and load the project by creating a new instance of the `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` class. This will allow you to query defined properties from the project and their evaluated values...

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;

...

public static string GetTargetPathFrom(EnvDTE.VsProject project)
{
    const string PropertyName = "TargetPath";
    return GetPropertyValueFrom(project.FileName, PropertyName);
}

public static string GetPropertyValueFrom(string projectFile, string propertyName)
{
    using (var projectCollection = new ProjectCollection())
    {
        var p = new Project(
            projectFile, 
            null, 
            null, 
            projectCollection, 
            ProjectLoadSettings.Default);

        return p.Properties
            .Where(x => x.Name == propertyName)
            .Select(x => x.EvaluatedValue)
            .SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

The sample provided above will use the default project build configuration; I haven´t tried it, but it may work to change the `Platform` and `Configuration` properties by passing global properties to the `Project` ctor. You could try this...

```
...

var globalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "Configuration", "Debug" }, 
        { "Platform", "AnyCPU" }
    };

var p = new Project(
    projectFile, 
    globalProperties, 
    null, 
    projectCollection,
    ProjectLoadSettings.Default);

...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i just have to change "var p = new Project"( to  "new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project" because of references conflicts.

Comment: 'Properties' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'Properties' could be found